# svn unable to connect to a repository at url

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, svn

I am using `Windows7 + TortoiseSVN 1.8.0.24401 (64bit)` svn was working fine but few weeks ago I installed `Avast Free Antivirus`, when try for svn-update it said:

[image]

I also want to share one issue more I think it relates with same. If in command prompt I type `ping google.com` it says:
[image]
It was sending responses before I installed anti virus. I un-installed anti virus, reinstalled SVN but could not fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the antivirus (temporarily) and try to update again?

Comment: yes I also tried it but no fix..

Comment: have you tried uninstalling it completely? disabling it may leave some configuration active on your system, like proxy-settings or hosts-entries